# Как создать условие с проверкой битовой маской в Laravel

Tags: laravel

Всем привет. Ситуация следующая, есть две таблицы, `contract` и `contract_group`

`contract` - имеет столбцы `id,title,gr` .... столбец `gr` содержит битовую маску.

`contract_group` - имеет столбцы `id,title`

столбец `gr` вычисляется по формуле `1<<gr1 | 1<<gr2...| 1<<grN`, где `gr1,gr2,grN` это `id` из таблицы `contract_group`.

Каким образом можно объединить две таблицы и получить группы для контракта? с помощью `with` не получится.

На данный момент сделал так:

```
public static function groups(){
    $contracts = self::get();
    $groups = GroupsContract::get();

    foreach ($contracts as $key => $contract){
        foreach ($groups as $group){

            if(($contract->gr & (1<<$group->id)) > 0){
                $contracts[$key]->attributes['groups'][] = $group;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но тут возникает много неудобный моментов, таких как нельзя добавить условий через модель и т.п

Comment: Я думаю, что средствами Eloqent напрямую этого не сделать. Есть мутаторы, но по ним вроде не получится сделать. А можно сделать так: создать представление в базе данных, соединив две таблицы с помощью битовых функций [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html). И это использовать в качестве модели. Либо разобраться с работой hasMany и сделать "свой аналог".

Comment: @TotalPusher спасибо. будем думать.

Comment: Добавили бы в текст вопроса минимальный пример (миграцию по созданию этих двух таблиц и наполнению данными), чтобы можно было воспроизвести быстрее ситуацию. И какая база - MySQL?

Comment: @TotalPusher база mysql, миграций нету, т.к вытаскиваю данные не из своей системы.